# Why ReLU function is not differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus

I'm kind of rusty in calculus.

Why is the [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) function not differentiable at $f(0)$?

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x \leq 0$} \\ 
x & \text{if $x > 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You should say “differentiable at $0$”, not “differentiable at $f(0)$”. (Not that it *actually* matters in this case, since $f(0)$ happens to be $0$, but anyway...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at $x > 0$, or the righthand derivative, $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} x = 1$$ for all $x$.

If you look at $x \le 0$, or the lefthand derivative, $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} 0 = 0$$ for all $x$.

Since $x = 0$ is the "break" point, the lefthand and righthand derivatives are not the same, and thus, the derivative is not defined at $x = 0$.

Comment: The derivative can exist without being continuous. You have argued that $f$ can't be continuously differentiable, but how about differentiable?

Comment: I'm saying that the left and right hand derivatives are not the same at $x=0$. Therefore, the derivative does not exist. I'm not really saying anything about continuity.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Coming back to this answer after more than a year, could you expand on what you meant? I think I had misunderstood your comment before.

Comment: What you computed is $\lim_{x\to0\pm}f'(x)$, whereas the one-sided derivatives at zero are $\lim_{h\to0\pm}h^{-1}[f(h)-f(0)]$. These are not the same thing! A function can be everywhere non-differentiable but it can still have one or both one-sided derivatives at zero. You observed that $f$ is differentiable whenever $x\neq0$ and that the limits at $x=0$ disagree. This only shows that if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, it cannot be continuous, unless you are implicitly appealing to a theorem that bridges the gap for you.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also find the computation of left and right derivatives at zero and the conclusion that the derivative cannot exist in Ovi's answer.

Answer (score 14):

Because it has a sharp corner at $0$, so it doesn't have a well defined tangent line; think about it, you can imagine many lines going through $(0, 0)$ that are tangent to the graph, so there are many possible tangent lines.

More formally, we have to investigate the limit

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}$$

This limit does not exist for the function, because if you let $h$ approach $0$ from the right, you get

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \dfrac {h-0}{h}=1.$$

While if you let $h$ approach $0$ from the left, that limit

$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \dfrac {0-0}{h}=0.$$

Therefore the limit does not exist, so the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: "a tangent line is one which touches the graph only at one point" isn't entirely true. Consider the tangent of $x^2(x-1)$ at $x = 0$. It intersects the graph at $x = 1$.

Comment: I would not call that sharp corner or bend at $0$ a "cusp". A cusp is when the curve kind of turns 180 degrees so that the incoming tangent vector has the opposite direction of the outgoing tangent vector. The function $x\mapsto\sqrt{|x|}$ has a cusp.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah I'm aware, but I think for the purposes of the OP it's fine. But I'm not actually sure of the definition of tangent line myself; the best thing I could think of is: "L is tangent to $f$ at $x$ if there exists some neighborhood around $x$ in which $L$ is either completely below or completely above the graph of $f$." This definition seems satisfactory to me from a geometric point of view; but then we would have to give up the notion that "derivatives give tangent lines," because for example $x^2 \sin (\frac 1x).$

Comment: The tangent of $x^3$ at $x = 0$ then becomes problematic. I don't think you can get a proper definition of tangent without going into derivatives, or at least the same kinds of limits as the ones that define derivatives.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Oh thanks for the info, I wasn't aware; my highschool teacher told us all of these sharp corners are cusps. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: @Arthur But if you define tangent line using derivative, then I think it becomes problematic with $x^2 \sin (\frac 1x)$ because (to me) that doesn't seem like it should be called a tangent line. I was giving priority to the geometric definition because the notion of tangent line is much older than the (analytic) idea of derivative.

Comment: @Arthur Oh but my definition wouldn't work with vertical tangent lines lol; I guess I would have to add "or is completely to the left or completely to the right" too.

Comment: For the case where the tangent "crosses" from lying on one side (say the lower side) to the other side of the curve, like $x\mapsto x^3$ mentioned above, see also [inflection point (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point).